# I'm getting a "1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found." error in Flutter using Dart with Cloud Firestore?

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: users.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index){
    return UserTile(sport: users[index]);
  },
);
```

I'm getting a "1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found." error and I don't know how to fix it. This is my UserTile file

```
class UserTile extends StatelessWidget {
     final Sport sport;
     UserTile(this.sport, {users});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Padding(
         padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
         child: Card(
             margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 6.0, 20.0, 0.0),
             child: ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                   radius: 25.0,
                   backgroundColor: Colors.brown[100],
                ),
                title: Text(sport.name),
                subtitle: Text('User plays ${sport.sport}'),
             ),
         ),
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

```dart
final Sport sport;
final Users users;
UserTile(this.sport, {users});
```

Means you can do this:

```
Sport sport = Sport();
UserTile(sport);
UserTile(sport,users:someUsers);
```

params out of `{}` or `[]`, means it is required, is same with other languages.

```dart
class UserTile{
  final Sport sport;
  UserTile(this.sport);
}
UserTile userTile = UserTile(sport);
```

params in `{}`, means it needs to be named.

```dart
class UserTile{
  final Sport? sport; //? means can be now.
final Sport requiredSport;// or required:
  UserTile({this.sport,required this.requiredSport});
}
UserTile userTile = UserTile(sport:sport,requiredsport:sport);
```

params in `[]`, means it's optional.

```dart
class UserTile{
  final Sport? sport; //? means can be now.
final Sport requiredSport;// or required:
  UserTile(this.requiredSport,[this.sport]);
}
UserTile userTile = UserTile(requiredSport,sport);
```